# Why cannot find symbol openOrCreateDatabase?

Tags: android, netbeans, sqlite

i am using Netbeans 7.3.1 and why i am getting this error 'can not find symbol' 
at openOrCreateDatabase while i have used this in Netbeans 7.2

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
SQLiteDatabase conn=null;
conn= openOrCreateDatabase("Net",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
```

Comment: are you performing this in activity class or plain java class?

Comment: i am using in java class.

Comment: I was stuck with same problem .I shifted over the activity then it worked for me.Try it if possible.

Comment: ok i will use this in Main activity.